# How to configure renovate to switch from gitlab-release to git-tags

Tags: gitlab-ci, renovate

My goal is to update all includes in my gitlab-ci.yml files. By default without any custom configuration renovate create MR with an include update based on gitlab-release.

But today, I have some includes only based on tag and there isn't any release associated to this tag. I looking for a solution to update also these includes.

To explain, if I have a release for `myprojet` named `1.2.3` and tag `1.2` and `1`

```yaml
include:
  # Bash template
  - project: "myproject"
    ref: "1.2.2"
    file: "templates/gitlab-ci.yml"
```

renovate detects there is a new release on 1.2.3 - It's OK
If I have :

```yaml
include:
  # Bash template
  - project: "myproject"
    ref: "1.1"
    file: "templates/gitlab-ci.yml"
```

renovate don't detect tag named `1.2` for `myproject`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried regex managers?
here's an example, change it for your needs:

```
  "regexManagers": [
    {
      "fileMatch": ["(^|/)\\.?gitlab-ci\\.yml$"],
      "matchStringsStrategy": "combination",
      "matchStrings": [
          "\\s\\sCHART_SOURCES_URL: \"(?<depName>.*?)\"\n",
              "\\s\\sCHART_SOURCES_VERSION: \"(?<currentValue>.*?)\"\n"
      ],
      "datasourceTemplate": "git-tags"
    }
  ],
```

i believe you could also set enabled=false for the actual gitlab-ci manager using matchManagers in package rules